# Uncaught TypeError when pushing to an array in the Vuex store's state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Using Vuex 4.0.0-beta.4, in my store I have:

```js
const state = {
  flash: []
};

const mutations = {
  PUSH_FLASH(state, payload) {
    debugger;
    state.flash.push(payload);
  }
};
```

And no matter what `payload` is (whether string, integer, or object), I get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Here is the full error:

[image: error1]

This began to occur after I updated from Vue2 to Vue3. Did I maybe forget to update some part of Vuex?

Comment: Did you mean `const state = { flash: [] }` ?

Comment: @Psidom, sorry, that was just a typo in my question. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had initially installed Vuex with `npm install vuex@4.0.0-beta.4`, but I should have done `npm install vuex@next`. After installing it properly, the error went away.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Spread syntax like in VUEX Documentation:

```
const state = {
  flash: []
};

const mutations = {
  PUSH_FLASH(state, payload) {
    state.flash = [...state.flash, payload]
  }
};
```